# Why is my Reactjs app URI showing the a replacement for :

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Route setup and its suppose to replace `:id` with the actual product ID for the URL path.  This is what the actual URL is showing as

`http://localhost:3000/product/$%7Bproduct._id`

Here is my App.js code:

```
<Router>
      <Header />
      <main className='py-3'>
        <Container>
          <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} /> <-- issue
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
```

I think its actually deeper in the Product.js file. It appear that Visual Studio Code is using the wrong single quote type when using $

Not sure how to force VSC to use the correct single quote type.

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
      <Link to={'/product/${product._id'}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top' />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={'/product/${product._id'}>
          <Card.Title as='div'>
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </Link>
        <Card.Text as='div'>
          <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`} />
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text as='h3'>${product.price}</Card.Text>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: `%7B` is `{`, not a colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with a link somewhere, not the route itself.

Somewhere you're linking to `product/${product._id}` without interpolation, like maybe this:

```
<Link to="product/${product._id}" />
```

instead of this:

```
<Link to={`product/${product._id}`} />
```

Comment: That is it. Visual Studio Code is using the worng type of single quote for interpolation ($). Not sure how to make VSC use the correct type? It might actually be Prettier doing it?

Comment: You need a [backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description), not a single quote.

Comment: Thats crap. Is that a react thing?

Comment: It's not a react thing. It's a [javascript template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description) thing.

Comment: Ok thanks. Right answer. No wonder I stayed away from JS for so long.

Comment: It's actually pretty awesome.